# Mapping gt and gT in VIM to command+shift+[ and command+shift+]

Tags: vim

I believe my question is pretty simple so this should be a piece of cake for you all.
So I just discovered the tabe command in VIM and would like to map the previous and next tab commands gt and gT to function the same as navigating between tabs in Chrome.

So, how do I map:

```
gt to command+shift+[

gT to command+shift+]
```

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to create a mapping using multiple modifier keys because Vim itself doesn't support it.

Since you appear to be on a Mac you can configure these shortcuts via the system preferences. In MacVim, note the exact names of the menu entries for "next tab" and "previous tab" and create two application-specific shortcuts.

If you use Vim in Terminal.app or iTerm.app it won't work because these apps don't have Vim-specific menu entries. You'd need to create your own [custom keybindings](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html) for your shortcuts to make them available to these apps.

May I suggest you to learn Vim's commands instead? They work unbelievably well.